# Why does permanent marker writing come off a white board when coated with white board marker?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

Why is it that dry erase markers allow permanent markings to come off?

Here's a [demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD-MJ-nF55M).

Comment: It's apparently the non-polar solvent that the dry erase marker contains: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_marker#Removal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solvent of the marker dissolves the permanent ink and mixes it with the whiteboard ink, leaving a dark dust that doesn't stick to the board.

The link in Wikipedia doesn't name common ethyl alcohol (denatured or not) as being a solvent for old marks. That is what I have used.